# Align WPF RibbonTextBox Problems

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I was creating an interface in using the Ribbon Control where I faced this problem. The screenshots below explain it.

[image]

The XAML Markup is as such.

```
<ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="PSO2" Header="Data Entry Section">
    <ribbon:RibbonTextBox Label="x1_min" SmallImageSource="Images/Document.png"  TextBoxWidth="50"/>
    <ribbon:RibbonTextBox Label="x1_max" SmallImageSource="Images/Document.png"  TextBoxWidth="50"/>
    <ribbon:RibbonTextBox Label="x2_min" SmallImageSource="Images/Document.png"  TextBoxWidth="50"/>
    <ribbon:RibbonTextBox Label="x2_max" SmallImageSource="Images/Document.png"  TextBoxWidth="50"/>
    <ribbon:RibbonTextBox Label="Iterations" SmallImageSource="Images/Document.png"  TextBoxWidth="50"/>
```

I wanted the TextBoxes to be exactly aligned however no matter whatever I did the didn't align. Setting or un-seeting the **TextBoxWidth** property didn't help either. Any solutions? Sorry I have <10 reputations so couldn't post an image directly.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: post the x1 max's xaml markup here

Comment: @Sivasubramanian Posted. Should I post the full XAML?

Comment: Hi Try removing the tag SmallImageSource in your XAML and let me whether you could align it properly??

Comment: Also why the alignment/margin of the control is not set??

Comment: @Sivasubramanian problem persists :( It looks even worse! Alignment/Margin setting doesn't prevent the problem.

Comment: Here is my tip to find the bug, name your RibbonTextboxes and on runtime put breakpoint on code cross check the width, alignment and margin for both properly aligned textbox and the improper one. this way you may track the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little hacky, but the solution I found is to forget about trying to align the elements using the Ribbon element alignment controls directly and align the elements using a grid within the `RibbonGroup`

The first challenge is the grid itself doesn't align properly within the ribbon group, but I solved that by binding the width of the grid to the width of the ribbon group, so it will be resized as the ribbon group gets resized.

The 2nd is aligning the labels since the label is part of the `RibbonTextBox` control.  The solution there is to use another control to provide the text label (`Label` or `TextBlock`) and just leave `RibbonTextBox.Label` blank.

```
<RibbonGroup x:Name="PSO2" Header="Data Entry Section" Width="270">
    <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=PSO2, Path=ActualWidth}" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="x1_min" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
        <RibbonTextBox Label="" SmallImageSource="Images/Document.png"  TextBoxWidth="50" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="x1_max" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <RibbonTextBox Label="" SmallImageSource="Images/Document.png"  TextBoxWidth="50" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="x2_min" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
        <RibbonTextBox Label="" SmallImageSource="Images/Document.png"  TextBoxWidth="50" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>

        <TextBlock Text="x2_max" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
        <RibbonTextBox Label="" SmallImageSource="Images/Document.png"  TextBoxWidth="50" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Iterations" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
        <RibbonTextBox Label="" SmallImageSource="Images/Document.png"  TextBoxWidth="50" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</RibbonGroup>
```

And using this, you end up with a RibbonGroup that looks like

[image]

The biggest limitation is the RibbonTextBox's image going to be misplaced between the label and the text box.  To overcome this, you would have to add an extra column set and put the icon in there instead of using RibbonTextBox.SmallImageSource